# How to list active sheets with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsx, openpyxl

I have an Excel sheet with 3 worksheets in it. I want to display a list of those sheets. This is what I have:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('examples.xlsx')

print(wb.get_sheet_names())
```

This it the error I'm getting:

```
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).

wb.get_sheet_names()
```

I'm using Pycharm CE and the example.xlsx is in the same folder as the python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an error, it's just a deprecation warning ([link](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html#Workbook.get_sheet_names)). Use `sheetnames` instead of `get_sheet_names()`.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('examples.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)
```